# How can I find all the self-answers available on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, self-answer, question-quality, statistics

I very much like self-answers. Over the last 7 years, I've written 4 of these myself. Q/A's about [Displaying characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747002/displaying-characters-with-dos-or-bios), [Displaying numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos), [Buffered input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works), and [Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101012/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multithreading-in-dos-e-g-when-solving-the-dining).
I believe the author of a self-answer can invest more time and deliver better in-depth coverage of the question at hand.

I would like to find **all the self-answers available on Stack Overflow**, but in the Advanced Search options I find nothing to filter e.g. on *asker* == *answerer*. Is there any way to get this result? I've seen that on Meta there's a tag named [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer). Perhaps we could have this on Stack Overflow too.

In relation to this I would like to find out the following statistics:

- How popular are self-answers?
- How often has the answer been split up due to the 30000 character space constraint and because the user has a lot more to talk about?
- Do self-answers often attract additional answers from other users?

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with the help of this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1288424)

```sql
;with self_q as
(
select q.id
     , max(len(a.body)) [max len]
     , (select count(*) 
        from posts p
        where p.parentid = q.id
        and p.owneruserid = q.owneruserid) [num_self]
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where q.owneruserid = a.owneruserid  
and q.posttypeid = 1 
and q.owneruserid is not null
and q.owneruserid > -1
group by q.id, q.owneruserid
)

select count( q.id) [self answer]
     , sum(q.answercount) [# answers]
     , sum(case when q.answercount = 1 then 1 else 0 end) [only OP answered]
     , sum(case when [max len] > 29000 then 1 else 0 end) [large answers]
     , sum(case when [num_self]>1 then 1 else 0 end) [OP more then one answer]
from posts q 
inner join self_q on self_q.id = q.id
```

I think I somewhat addressed the stats you mentioned in the bullets.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).